# Using a "for" loop to calculate incremented data point in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

My question is how would i go about using a FOR loop (or a better recommended strategy)to print out different results based on user input.

OK, let me elaborate more.

I was mistaken with my explanation, due to not thinking it thru. i apologize.

A user enters a minimum 0f 1000 psi, then a maximum of 3000 psi.
then the amount of samples to be taken. We will say  samples at intervals of 100 psi.

Example:

1. enter minimum pressure   //1000 psi
2. enter maximum pressure   //3000 psi
3. what is the interval between sample (pressure) //50 psi
4. for every interval calculateDensity

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define N2Denstiy 1.251 //1.251 g/l  mole weight
#define ATM 0.0680459639 //Pressure in PSI time ATM
#define R 0.08206 //gas constant


float calculateDensity(float pres, float temp, float moleWeight);

float calculateDensity(float pres, float temp, float moleWeight) {

return moleWeight * (pres * ATM) / (temp * R);

}


int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
 {
  float result;
  float temp = 77.0;

  float i, min_pressure, max_pressure, sample_interval;

  printf("Enter minimum Pressure, maximum pressure and interval: ");

  scanf("%f %f %f", &min_pressure, &max_pressure, &sample_interval);

  for(i = min_pressure; i <=max_pressure; i = i + sample_interval) 



    // result = calculateDensity(i, temp, N2Denstiy);
    //      printf("%f\n",result);

  printf("%f ", i);
  printf("\n");


  return 0;

}
```

The results here are correct for the basic loop. However, I want to calculateDensity then display the results.

Enter minimum Pressure, maximum pressure and interval: 1000 3000 50
1000.000000 1050.000000 1100.000000 1150.000000 1200.000000 1250.000000 1300.000000       1350.000000 1400.000000 1450.000000 1500.000000 1550.000000 1600.000000 1650.000000 1700.000000 1750.000000 1800.000000 1850.000000 1900.000000 1950.000000 2000.000000 2050.000000 2100.000000 2150.000000 2200.000000 2250.000000 2300.000000 2350.000000 2400.000000 2450.000000 2500.000000 2550.000000 2600.000000 2650.000000 2700.000000 2750.000000 2800.000000 2850.000000 2900.000000 2950.000000 3000.000000

Comment: If you calculate 30 samples with 50psi distance you only cover a range of 29*50psi = 1450psi. How does this correspond to your min/max values? Or have I misunderstood something completely?

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

```
float i;
for(i = min_pressure; i <= max_pressure; + += increment_pressure) {
    calculatePressure(i, temp, moleWeight);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Say you number if samples is `numSamples`:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < numSamples ; i++ )
{
    //get data from user - pres, temp, moleWeight
    float result = calculateDensity(pres, temp, moleWeight);
    printf("%f\n",result);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question you want:

```
int i;
for(i = 0; i < sample_interval && increment_pressure * i + min_pressure < max_pressure; i++) {
     printf("%f\n", calculatePressure(increment_pressure * i + min_pressure, temp, moleWeight));
}
```